# Print all content in aspx page including embedded pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have an aspx page that i need to be able to print out. Inside my page i embed a pdf that is displayed using a cdn as the src. 
Since it is a pdf and it is embedded but being hosted on another site when i try to print the page even though it displays correctly the element shows as empty. How can i capture everything in the DOM including the embedded pdf?

I have tried to use the jspdf library to no avail.

```
<embed src='https://image.pdf' style="width: 607px; height: 500px"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to print everything inside the browser window then maybe use print function of [window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)?

```
window.print();
```